# $\{1, 2, . . . , 49\}$ is partitioned into $3$ subsets. Prove that at least $1$ of them contains $3$ different numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a+b=c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

As the title says, I'm asked to prove that at least one of the subsets contains three different numbers $a, b$ and c such that $a + b = c$. I tried to prove it but it is more difficult than it initially seemed to be. How would you do it?

Edit: The original set is arbitrarily partitioned.

Edit2: The exercise was given in a first year Discrete Mathematics course. I'm pretty sure they want us to somehow use the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: By [Schur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_theorem) the numbers from $1$ to $14$ already have the desired property, since $14$ is the third [Schur's number](http://oeis.org/A030126)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you show what you have tried? That helps others to write better answers.

Comment: Alessandro, if I'm not mistaken, to use that you would have to prove that three numbers from 1 to 14 are contained in one of the three subsets. How would you do that?

Comment: @Rr.Mar: No, you wouldn’t. The result in question is that if $n\ge 14$, in any partition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into three parts at least one part contains distinct $x,y,z$ such that $x+y=z$.

Comment: @Alessandro: That’s true, but the problem here is presumably to find a reasonably elementary proof for the case $n=49$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree, that's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer, I suppose there should be an easier proof having much more numbers than necessary available

Comment: At least one of the set contains numbers whose sum is at least 405. Don't know how that helps, and the sum 41 +... + 49 = 405

Comment: @zhoraster : how is this inequality related to the original problem?

Comment: @zhoraster : in other words, the original question is a particular case of the Schur's theorem. am i correct?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made another edit specifying the sort of proof they are expecting.

Comment: What is wrong with the partitioning of $1$ to $16$ into $\{1,2,4,7,10,13\} , \{3,5,6,12,14,16\}$ and $\{8,9,11,15\}$ ?

Comment: @Alessandro Schur's theorem does not require the $3$ numbers to be different...but the OP here said that $a,b,c$ are different.

Comment: See this: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h565372p3306745

Comment: @IndrayudhRoy I had overlooked that detail, you are right, Schur's theorem can't be used here

Answer (score 3):

An informal proof with contradiction:

Assume that there is no such subset.

By pigeonhole principle, there must be one subset (of the three), say $A$, has at least $17$ elements, say $a_1<a_2<...<a_{17}$. Form assumption we know if the difference $a_{17}-a_i \neq a_i$, $i=1,2,...,16$, then it will not belong to $A$. There can be at most one $i$ s.t. $a_{17}-a_i=a_i$.

Then, by pigeonhole principle again, one of the rest two subsets, say $B$, must have at least $8$ of those differences $a_{17}-a_i$ which are not in $A$, say $b_1<b_2<...<b_8$, and similarly, if the difference $b_8-b_j \neq b_j$, $j=1,2,...,7$, then it will not belong to $B$. There can be at most one $j$ s.t. $b_8-b_j=b_j$.

For any $j$ there won't be such $j' \neq j$ that $b_{j'}-b_j \in A$. If there was one, then $b_j=a_{17}-a_{i'}$ and $b_j=a_{17}-a_i$, then $(a_{17}-a_{i'})-(a_{17}-a_i)=a_i-a_{i'} \in A$ where $i \neq i'$, a contradiction.

So those $8$ (or $7$) differences must be in the last subset, say $C$. We can order them and denote them by $c_1<c_2<...<c_7$ (or $c_8$). But similarly, only at most one of their differences $c_8-c_k$ (or $c_7-c_k$) will lie in $C$. The others are not in $B$, either. While If $c_8-c_k \in A$ then there is $b_j-b_{j'} \in A$, and this is impossible, thus, they are not in $A$.

This contradicts with the fact that $A$, $B$ and $C$ consist of a partition.

Comment: "Informal" here means "ugly"... any suggestion is welcome :)